# Parse website and save a specific DIV using 'PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to using 'PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser' to parse a website and save a specific 'div' as a 'HTM' file. I have tried some things but I'm unable to save the div.

Below is the 'PHP' code I have tried but get an error as `$div->save('site/test.htm');` is not correct.

```
include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html('http://roosterteeth.com/home.php');
foreach ($html->find('div.streamIndividual') as $div) {
$div->save('site/test.htm');
};
```

I hope you can help me and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html('http://roosterteeth.com/home.php');
foreach ($html->find('div.streamIndividual') as $div) 
{
  file_put_contents('site/test.htm', $div);
}
```

This will overwrite the file though on each loop so using something like this will stop that

```
file_put_contents('site/test.htm', $div, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm):

> `$e->outertext` *Read or write the outer HTML text of element.*
>   `echo $e->outertext; // Returns: " <div>foo <b>bar</b></div>"`

Hence:

```
include( 'site/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = file_get_html('http://roosterteeth.com/home.php');
foreach ($html->find('div.streamIndividual') as $div) 
{
    file_put_contents('site/test.htm', $div->outertext);
}
```